# FPDF utf-8 encoding (HOW-TO)

Tags: unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, fpdf

Does anybody know how to set the encoding in FPDF package to UTF-8? Or at least to ISO-8859-7 (Greek) that supports Greek characters?

Basically I want to create a PDF file containing Greek characters.

Any suggestions would help.
George

Comment: If you want to use more languages you need UTF8, so you may use tFPDF. Have a look at the [composer package](https://packagist.org/packages/docnet/tfpdf).

Comment: Look for Daan's answer for the best answer!

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Don't use UTF-8 encoding. Standard FPDF fonts use ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252. It is possible to perform a conversion to ISO-8859-1 with `utf8_decode()`:
`$str = utf8_decode($str);`
But some characters such as Euro won't be translated correctly. If the iconv extension is available, the right way to do it is the following:
`$str = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $str);`

Comment: where to place UTF-8 in fpdf that could print arbic text

Comment: I don't think this will help. Your answer does explain how to generate a PDF with ISO-8859-1 or windows-1252 encoding, but these encodings will not work for non-latin languages. Not to mention outputting multi-language (multi-script) texts.

Comment: @Rafiq: dont use the "old" FPDF but the newer UTF8 Version tFPDF as postet in my Answer.

Comment: @Tarsis' answer should be upvoted more; tFPDF's UTF-8 support addresses all of this.

Comment: Note: When using ISO-8859-1, the € character will not work (there is no Euro sign in the charset, use ISO-8859-15 instead).

Comment: @BurninLeo: ISO-8859-15 is not much better, all those Encodings have the same limit of Characters, so -15 has € but therefore is missing ´ or ½. The only real solution is to use UTF-8 instead of avoiding it - as shown in my answer.

Comment: Good point - I was so busy with solving the issue that I actually stepped over tFPDF... Arg!

Comment: tFPDF does support unicode but it has not been updated in 3 years, where as FPDF has been updated more recently making tFPDF outdated. Please keep that in mind when using tFPDF.

Comment: I tried using tFPDF but I am also using the Transformations and CircularText extensions and the UTF8 characters would not display correctly in the circular text.  Passing the text through iconv worked and was a simpler solution for my situation.

Comment: @phansen: I use tFPDF with fpdf-scripts. For migration CircularText only a few changes are necessary. At first parsing text:
        $utf_text = preg_split('//u', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        $length = count($utf_text);
or you can use Multibyte String Functions for parsing.
Then replace strlen($text) with $length and $text with $utf_text.

Comment: this one really fix my problem, since fpdf cannot print some country's language, but with this tips it can be done. also TFPDF doesnot work some character show wrong (ex. Thai)

Answer (score 47):

You have two options to achieve real UTF-8 support:

**1. Use official UTF-8 Version tFPDF**

There also is a official UTF-8 Version of FPDF called tFPDF http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php

You can easyly switch from the original FPDF, just make sure you also use a unicode Font as shown in the example in the above link or my code:

```php
<?php

//this is a UTF-8 file, we won't need any encode/decode/iconv workarounds

//define the path to the .ttf files you want to use
define('FPDF_FONTPATH',"../fonts/");
require('tfpdf.php');
    
$pdf = new tFPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
    
// Add Unicode fonts (.ttf files)
$fontName = 'Helvetica';
$pdf->AddFont($fontName,'','HelveticaNeue LightCond.ttf',true);
$pdf->AddFont($fontName,'B','HelveticaNeue MediumCond.ttf',true);

//now use the Unicode font in bold
$pdf->SetFont($fontName,'B',12);

//anything else is identical to the old FPDF, just use Write(),Cell(),MultiCell()... 
//without any encoding trouble
$pdf->Cell(100,20, "Some UTF-8 String");

//...
?>
```

I think its much more elegant to use this instead of spaming utf8_decode() everywhere and the ability to use .ttf files directly in AddFont() is an upside too.

Any other answer here is just a way to avoid or work around the problem, and avoiding UTF-8 is no real option for an up to date project.

**2. Use an alternative Project like mPDF or TCPDF**

There are also alternatives that I would prefer like mPDF or TCPDF (and others) wich base on FPDF but offer advanced functions, have UTF-8 Support, can interpret HTML Code (limited of course as there is no direct way to convert HTML to PDF) and are under active developement.
Most of the FPDF code can be used directly in those librarys, so its pretty easy to migrate the code.

https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf

https://github.com/tecnickcom/tcpdf

Comment: None of the iconv and decode solutions works for the more exceptional characters (♠♥☺äκόσμος). But if you just replace your fpdf.php with the tpdf.php file, it all just starts working and your files get smaller as an extra bonus. Great fix.

Comment: Are FPDF and tFPDF separate branches? Does anyone know the reason why is tFPDF hidden so well on the FPDF page? Are there any drawbacks, one should know before switching?

Comment: I am nut sure why they didnt make it the default FPDF Version, but it is linked directly on the main page http://www.fpdf.org/ and as mentioned there the features of tFPDF were originally developed for mPDF. I have used tFPDF for a lot of PDFs in a productive environment and i think besides the UTF-8 and font changes it is 100% the same. Never had any issues.

Comment: tFPDF is a script, or an extension of FPDF. It is considered outdated (Updated 3 years ago) because FPDF has been updated more recently. The author of tFPDF does not keep it maintained and the GitHub associated with tFPDF has not been touched. See: https://github.com/rev42/tfpdf

Comment: As long as you dont need more functions i dont see a Problem in that, btw the last (minor) Update was only 4 Months ago - still better than not supporting UTF-8. Either way i would preffer TCPDF or mPDF, which both base on FPDF but give advanced functions and also support HTML Code.

Comment: Nowadays tFPDF can be installed via composer: https://packagist.org/packages/docnet/tfpdf

Comment: It works, but it's muuuuuch slower for me than the original FPDF. I ran the native FPDF version to create three A4 PDFs, and it took 577ms to run. I ran the same script but with the tFPDF swapped in to replace native FPDF and it took a whopping 43 seconds. The files were a little over half the size, though.

Answer (score 43):

there is a really simple solution for this problem.

In the file fpdf.php go to the line that says:

```
if($txt!=='')
{
```

It is line 648 in my version of fpdf.
Insert the following line of code:

```
$txt = iconv('utf-8', 'cp1252', $txt);
```

(above the line of code)

```
if($align=='R')
```

This works for all German special characters and should also work for Greek special characters. Otherwise simply replace cp1252 with the respective alphabet you require. You can see all supported characters here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252

I saw the solution here: http://fudforum.org/forum/index.php?t=msg&goto=167345
Please use my example code above, as the original author forgot to insert a dash between utf and 8.

Hope the above was helpful.

Daan

Comment: Perfect, this is still working or needed after updating FPDF to a version that supports PHP7 to show special characters correctely.

Comment: This command work  for me,   $txt = iconv('utf-8', 'cp1252', $txt);    Thks

Comment: Just amazing simpel solution. Sad it is tucked away in a obscure place on stackoverflow :)

Comment: This changed something with my spacing - some lines break earlier now. But at least it seems to work - before Turkish letter didn't work at all for me, now at least I see something.

Comment: It's 2024 and still the best answer for me after updating my old XAMPP. @Cold_class - any sideffects other than that?

Comment: @Zim84 I don't know of any - once I got this to work 4 years ago I never looked at it again xD

Answer (score 10):

You need to generate a font first. You must use the `MakeFont` utility included within the FPDF package. I used on Linux this a bit extended script from the demo:

```
<?php
// Generation of font definition file for tutorial 7
require('../makefont/makefont.php');

$dir = opendir('/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/');
while (($relativeName = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
    if ($relativeName == '..' || $relativeName == '.')
        continue;
    MakeFont("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/$relativeName",'ISO-8859-2');
}
?>
```

Then I copied generated files to the `font` directory of my web and used this:

```
$pdf->Cell(80,70, iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-2', 'Buňka jedna'),1);
```

(I was working on a table.) That worked for my language (*Buňka jedna* is czech for *Cell one*). Czech language belongs to central european languages, also ISO-8859-2. Regrettably the user of FPDF is forced to lost advantages of UTF-8 encoding. You cannot get this in your PDF:

```
Městečko Fruens Bøge
```

Danish letter `ø` becomes `ř` in ISO-8859-2.

**Suggestion of solution:** You need to get a Greek font, generate the font using proper encoding (ISO-8859-7) and use `iconv` with the same target encoding as the one the font has been generated with.

Answer (score 8):

***How do I create PDF's in FPDF that support Chinese, Japanese, Russian, etc.?***

[image]

(snapshots of code in use below)

I'd like to provide: a summary of the problem, the solution, a github project with the working code, and an online example with the expected, resultant PDF.

*The Problem :*

1. As stated by Tarsis, swap FPDF to TFPDF.
2. You actually need a font that supports the UTF-8 characters you are using.

   I.E., merely using Helvetica and trying to display Japanese will not work.  If you use Font Forge, or some other font tool, you can scroll to the Chinese characters of the font, and see that they are blank.

   Google has a font ([Noto font](https://www.google.com/get/noto/)) that contains all languages, and it is 20mb, which is usually several factors the size of your text.  So, you can see why many fonts simply won't cover every single language.

*The Solution :*

I'm using rounded-mgenplus-20140828.ttf and ZCOOL_QingKe_HuangYou.ttf font packs for Japanese and Chinese, which are open source and can be found in many open source projects.  In tFPDF itself, or a new inheriting class of it, like `class HTMLtoPDF extends tFPDF {...}`, you'll do this...

```
$this->AddFont('japanese', '', 'rounded-mgenplus-20140828.ttf', true);
$this->SetFont('japanese', '', 14);
$this->Write(14, '日本語');
```

Should be nothing more to it!

*Code Package on GitHub :*

https://github.com/HoldOffHunger/php-html-to-pdf

*Working, Online Demo of Japanese :*

https://www.earthfluent.com/privacy.pdf?language=ja

Answer (score 6):

This answer didn't work for me, I needed to run html decode on the string also.  See

```
iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', html_entity_decode($str));
```

Props go to emfi from [html_entity_decode in FPDF(using tFPDF extention)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516960/html-entity-decode-in-fpdfusing-tfpdf-extention/16647521#16647521)

Answer (score 5):

just edit the function cell in the fpdf.php file, look for the line that looks like this

```
function cell ($w, $h = 0, $txt = '', $border = 0, $ln = 0, $align = '', $fill = false, $link = '')
{
```

after finding the line

write after the `{`,

```
$txt = utf8_decode($txt);
```

save the file and ready, the accents and the utf8 encoding will be working :)

Answer (score 4):

There is an extension of FPDF called mPDF that allows Unicode fonts.

http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php

Comment: Link seems to be dead

Answer (score 4):

None of the above solutions are going to work.

Try this:

```
function filter_html($value){
    $value = mb_convert_encoding($value, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
    return $value;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make a class to extend FPDF and add this:

```
class utfFPDF extends FPDF {

function Cell($w, $h=0, $txt="", $border=0, $ln=0, $align='', $fill=false, $link='')
{
    if (!empty($txt)){
        if (mb_detect_encoding($txt, 'UTF-8', false)){
            $txt = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-5', $txt);

        }
    }
    parent::Cell($w, $h, $txt, $border, $ln, $align, $fill, $link);

}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to answer this for anyone who hasn't switched over to **TFPDF** for whatever reason (framework integration, etc.)

Go to: http://www.fpdf.org/makefont/index.php

Use a `.ttf` compatible font for the language you want to use. Make sure to choose the encoding number that is correct for your language. Download the files and paste them in your current FPDF font directory.

Use this to activate the new font:  `$pdf->AddFont($font_name,'','Your_Font_Here.php');`

Then you can use `$pdf->SetFont` normally.

On the font itself, use iconv to convert to UTF-8. So if for example you're using Hebrew, you would do `iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1255', $first_name)`.

Substitute the windows encoding number for your language encoding.

For right to left, a quick fix is doing something like `strrev(iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1255', $first_name))`.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply this function on your text :

```
 $yourtext = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $yourtext);
```

Thanks

Comment: This has worked for me to display the characters `±` and `–` in my FPDF generated PDF.

Answer (score 2):

Like many said here:

```
$yourtext = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $yourtext);
```

**BUT**! with an `'//Ignore'` after the windows-1252 or in my case CP1252, like this:

```
iconv("UTF-8", "CP1252//IGNORE", $row['project_name'])
```

This one worked for me, I hope it works for you!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it will do for Greek, but I had the same issue for Brazilian Portuguese characters and my solution was to use html entities. I had basically two cases:

1. String *may* contain UTF-8 characters.

For these, I first encoded it to html entities with `htmlentities()` and then decoded them to `iso-8859-1`. Example:

```
$s = html_entity_decode(htmlentities($my_variable_text), ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, 'iso-8859-1');
```

2. Fixed string with html entities:

For these, I just left `htmlentities()` call out. Example:

```
$s = html_entity_decode("Treasurer/Tr&eacute;sorier", ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, 'iso-8859-1');
```

Then I passed `$s` to FPDF, like in this example:

```
$pdf->Cell(100, 20, $s, 0, 0, 'L');
```

Note: `ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401` is the standard value for parameter #2, as in http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

For offsprings.

How I managed to add russian language to fpdf on my Linux machine:

1) Go to http://www.fpdf.org/makefont/ and convert your ttf font(for example AerialRegular.ttf) into 2 files **using ISO-8859-5 encoding**: AerialRegular.php and AerialRegular.z

2) Put these 2 files into **fpdf/font** directory

3) Use it in your code:

```
$pdf = new \FPDI();
    $pdf->AddFont('ArialMT','','ArialRegular.php');
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0, 211, 297); //width and height in mms
    $pdf->SetFont('ArialMT','',35);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(255,0,0);
    $fullName = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-5', 'Алексей');
    $pdf->SetXY(60, 54);
    $pdf->Write(0, $fullName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this iconv solution:

```
$str = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $str);
```

You could use the following:

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-8", "Windows-1252");
```

See: [How to convert Windows-1252 characters to values in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35234129/how-to-convert-windows-1252-characters-to-values-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

There's an extention to FPDF called UFDPF
http://acko.net/blog/ufpdf-unicode-utf-8-extension-for-fpdf/

But, imho, it's better to use mpdf if you're it's possible for you to change class.

Answer (score 0):

I use FPDF for ASP, and the iconv function is not available.
It seems strange, by I solved the UTF-8 problem by **adding a fake image** (an 1x1px jpeg) to the pdf, just after the AddPage() function:

```
pdf.Image "images/fpdf.jpg",0,0,1
```

In this way, accented characters are correctly added to my pdf, don't ask me why but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is old but I think my answer would help those who haven't found solution in other answers. So, my problem was that I couldn't display croatian characters in my PDF. Firstly, I used FPDF but, I think, it does not support Unicode. Finally, what solved my problem is tFPDF which is the version of FPDF that supports Unicode. This is the example that worked for me:

```
require('tFPDF/tfpdf.php');
$pdf = new tFPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf',true);
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu', 'B', 'DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf', true);

$pdf->SetFont('DejaVu','',14);

$txt = 'čćžšđČĆŽŠĐ';
$pdf->Write(8,$txt);

$pdf->Output();
```

Answer (score 0):

For me none of the answered worked. I just wanted to print some symbols. So this was my code which worked.

```
$pdf->AddFont('Symbol','','symbol.php');
$pdf->SetFont('Symbol','',35);
$pdf->Write(10,chr(229));
```