# html_entity_decode in FPDF(using tFPDF extension)

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, html-encode

I am using tFPDF to generate a PDF.  The php file is UTF-8 encoded.
I want `&copy;` for example, to be output in the pdf as the copyright symbol.

I have tried `iconv`, `html_entity_decode`, `htmlspecialchars_decode`.  When I take the string I am trying to decode and hard-code it in to a different file and decode it, it works as expected.  So for some reason it is not being output in the PDF.  I have tried output buffering.  I am using `DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf` (true type fonts).

Link to tFPDF:  http://fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php

I am out of ideas.  I tried double decoding, I checked everywhere to make sure it was not being encoded anywhere else.

Comment: [Possible dup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327960/convert-delascii-characters-delinsentity-codes-ins-to-utf8-in-mysql-on-t), with no answer `:(`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you need this:

```
iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', html_entity_decode($str));
```

the **html_entity_decode** decodes the html entities. but due to any reason you must convert it to utf8 with **iconv**. i suppose this is a fpdf-secret... cause in normal browser view it is displayed correctly.

Comment: in any pdf-output you wanna make. for example: $pdf->Write(5, iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', html_entity_decode($str)));

Answer (score 3):

Actully, fpdf project FAQ has an explanation for it:

http://www.fpdf.org/~~V/en/FAQ.php#q7

> Don't use UTF-8 encoding. Standard FPDF fonts use ISO-8859-1 or
>   Windows-1252. It is possible to perform a conversion to ISO-8859-1
>   with utf8_decode():

```
$str = utf8_decode($str);
```

> But some characters such as Euro won't be translated correctly. If the
>   iconv extension is available, the right way to do it is the following:

```
$str = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $str);
```

So, as emfi suggests, a combination of iconv() and html_entity_decode() PHP functions is the solution to your question:

```
$str = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', html_entity_decode("&copy;"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there is no automatic conversion available from HTML entity codes to their UTF-8 equivalents. In cases like this I have resorted to manual string replacement, eg:

```
$strOut = str_replace( "&copy;", "\xc2\xa9", $strIn );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fix the problem with this code:

```
$str = utf8_decode($str);
$str = html_entity_decode($str);
$str =  iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252',$str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `setFont('Symbol')` or `setFont('ZapfDingbats')` to select the special characters that you want to print.

```
define('TICK', chr(214)); # in font 'Symbol' -> print a tick symbol
...
$this->SetFont('Symbol', 'B', 8);
$this->Cell(5, 5, TICK, 0, 'L');    # will output the symbol to PDF
```

Output: √

This way, you won't need to convert to ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252 OR use another library tFPDF for special characters :)

Refer: http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script4.php for font & character list