# html_entity_decode in FPDF

Tags: php, pdf

I Have the some problem als this post from 2 year ago on this website. I tried everything, but nothing help.

Does anybody over here a working solutions for this problem?

---

[html_entity_decode in FPDF(using tFPDF extention)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516960/html-entity-decode-in-fpdfusing-tfpdf-extention?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

I am using tFPDF to generate a PDF. The php file is UTF-8 encoded. I want © for example, to be output in the pdf as the copyright symbol.

I have tried iconv, html_entity_decode, htmlspecialchars_decode. When I take the string I am trying to decode and hard-code it in to a different file and decode it, it works as expected. So for some reason it is not being output in the PDF. I have tried output buffering. I am using DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf (true type fonts).

Link to tFPDF: http://fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php

I am out of ideas. I tried double decoding, I checked everywhere to make sure it was not being encoded anywhere else.

Help!

Comment: If you pass © in UTF-8 encoding to tFPDF it should work without touching the variable at all. What's the source of the "©"-sign?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The source is a Database, and it was saved as &copy;

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me??