# utf8 decode for fpdf in php

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I generate pdf file for personal detail of a person. I added language field in that pdf page. I using more than 48 country languages print in my pdf.

example of language list are:    Afrikaans, Bahasa Indonesia, Bahasa Melayu, Català, Čeština, Cymraeg, Dansk, Deutsch, English (UK), English (US), Español, Español (España), Euskara, Filipino, Français (Canada), Français (France), Hrvatski, Italiano, Lietuvių, Magyar, Nederlands, Norsk (bokmål), Polski, Português (Brasil), Português (Portugal), Română, Slovenčina, Slovenščina, Suomi, Svenska, Tiếng Việt, Türkçe, Ελληνικά, Български, Русский, Српски, हिन्दी, বাংলা, ਪੰਜਾਬੀ, தமிழ், తెలుగు, മലയാളം, ภาษาไทย, 한국어, 中文(台灣), 中文(简体), 中文(香港), 日本語

I need to print same format of all language in my fpdf php page. now i using below code in my php file.

header("Content-type: application/pdf; charset=utf-8");
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");

I assign all language in this variable $language

$language= utf8_decode($language);
$pdf->MultiCell(80,6,$language,0,1,'L');

I got output like this:

Afrikaans, Bahasa Indonesia, Bahasa Melayu, CatalÃ ,
Ä?eÅ¡tina, Cymraeg, Dansk, Deutsch, English (UK),
English (US), EspaÃ±ol, EspaÃ±ol (EspaÃ±a), Euskara,
Filipino, FranÃ§ais (Canada), FranÃ§ais (France),
Hrvatski, Italiano, LietuviÅ³, Magyar, Nederlands, Norsk
(bokmÃ¥l), Polski, PortuguÃªs (Brasil), PortuguÃªs
(Portugal), RomÃ¢nÄ?, SlovenÄ•ina, SlovenÅ¡Ä•ina,
Suomi, Svenska, Tiáº¿ng Viá»?t, TÃ¼rkÃ§e,
Î?Î»Î»Î·Î½Î¹ÎºÎ¬, Ð?Ñ?Ð»Ð³Ð°Ñ?Ñ•ÐºÐ¸, Ð Ñ?Ñ•Ñ•ÐºÐ¸Ð¹,
Ð¡Ñ?Ð¿Ñ•ÐºÐ¸, à¤¹à¤¿à¤¨à¥•à¤¦à¥?, à¦¬à¦¾à¦?à¦²à¦¾,
à¨ªà©°à¨?à¨¾à¨¬à©?, à®¤à®®à®¿à®´à¯•,
à°¤à±?à°²à±•à°?à±•, à´®à´²à´¯à´¾à´³à´?,
à¸ à¸²à¸©à¸²à¹?à¸?à¸¢, í??êμì?
´, ä¸æ??(
å•°ç•£),
ä¸æ??(
ç®?ä½?), ä¸æ??(
é¦?æ¸¯), æ?¥æ?¬èª?

I need to generate pdf in original format of all langauge text.

Comment: Apparently [utf-8 does not work with FPDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334134/fpdf-utf-8-encoding-how-to), but take a look at [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php) which is based on FPDF.

Answer (score 1):

I use this code all of the time with FPDF to display UTF-8 characters.

```
iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', value)
```

Answer (score 1):

FPDF has problems with UTF8 ... heres a quick fix that may help:

```
class PDF extends FPDF {

    function Cell( $w, $h = 0, $t = '', $b = 0, $l = 0, $a = '', $f = false, $y = '' ) {

        parent::Cell( $w, $h, iconv( 'UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $t ), $b, $l, $a, $f, $y );

    }

}
```

Of course it is necessary to call the extension and not the initial FPDF class:

```
$pdf = new PDF( 'P', 'mm', 'A4' );
```