# Generate PDF file in my web app by using php

Tags: php, fpdf

I want to generate a **PDF** file in my web app. I am using php and I tried [**fpdf library**](http://www.fpdf.org/) 
I tried to create `pdf` by using following code:

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Привет мир!');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

It works when we use english characters inside file, but file encoding is `ANSI` and inside writen russian characters I get that error:

[image]

if I change file encoding to `utf-8` get error:

```
FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file (output started at Z:\home\fpdf\www\tutorial\tuto1.php:1)
```

Who knows how to resolve the problem, please help me !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334134/fpdf-utf-8-encoding-how-to

Answer (score 1):

```
$pdf->Cell(40,10, iconv('UTF-8', 'CP-1251', $str) );
```

Make sure you're saving your document as UTF8