# UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2013' (writing to PDF)

Tags: python, pdf, unicode, fpdf, python-3.7

I am having an issue with `Unicode` with a variable contents when writing to a .pdf with python.

**It's outputting this error:**

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2013'
```

Which is it getting caught on an em dash basically.

I have tried taking that variable, where the contents has an 'em dash' and redefined it with an '`.encode('utf-8')`' for example, i.e., below:

```
Body = msg.Body

BodyC = Body.encode('utf-8')
```

And now I get the **below error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 37, in <module>
    pdf.cell(200, 10, txt="Bod: " + BodyC,  ln=4, align="C")
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

Below is my full code, how could I simply fix my Unicode error in '`Body`' variable contents.

Converting to `utf-8` or `western`, anything outside of '`latin-1`'. Any suggestions?

**Full Code:**

```
from fpdf import FPDF
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(r"C:\User\language\python\Msg-To-PDF\test_msg.msg")

print (msg.SenderName)
print (msg.SenderEmailAddress)
print (msg.SentOn)
print (msg.To)
print (msg.CC)
print (msg.BCC)
print (msg.Subject)
print (msg.Body)

SenderName = msg.SenderName
SenderEmailAddress = msg.SenderEmailAddress
SentOn = msg.SentOn
To = msg.To
CC = msg.CC
BCC = msg.BCC
Subject = msg.Subject
Body = msg.Body
BodyC = Body.encode('utf-8')

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()

# pdf.add_font('DejaVu', '', 'DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf', uni=True)
pdf.set_font("Helvetica", style = '', size = 11)
pdf.cell(200, 10, txt="From: " + SenderName, ln=1, align="C")
# pdf.cell(200, 10, border=SentOn, ln=1, align="C")
pdf.cell(200, 10, txt="To: " + To, ln=1, align="C")
pdf.cell(200, 10, txt="CC: " + CC, ln=1, align="C")
pdf.cell(200, 10, txt="BCC: " + BCC, ln=1, align="C")
pdf.cell(200, 10, txt="Subject: " + Subject, ln=1, align="C")
pdf.cell(200, 10, txt="Bod: " + BodyC,  ln=4, align="C")

pdf.output("Sample.pdf")
```

- **How can I change out of `'latin1'`?**

---

- Anyway to just globally fix these issues?

---

Comment: Have you tried casting the msg.Body with `str(msg.Body)`?

Comment: Where, what do you mean?

Comment: `Body = msg.Body` -> `Body = str(msg.Body)` ?

Comment: It still produces the exact same error 'UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 485: ordinal not in range(256)'

Comment: Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539881/python-converting-from-iso-8859-1-latin1-to-utf-8

Comment: `BodyC = Body.encode('utf-8')` actually does nothing! Another point is `\u2013` error output is `unicode` but system-wide encoding not set properly. Some warnings: User_class which sub_process is calling with default encoding ? most encoding errors throw by from nonRAW file/IO objects.  @ladygremlin whindows always excepting this errors, I solved the system-wide encoding by UTF-8 (not Unicode).

Comment: @dsgdfg Ahhh, I didn't realize Windows always throws this. That's not my OS of choice. :)

Comment: on python idle `'\x64\x45'+'teest' = 'dEteest'` mean i used `python2.7.X` so if use `python3.x` convert bytes to string with source encoding.

Comment: @dsgdfg Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python : UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290206/python-unicodeencodeerror-latin-1-codec-cant-encode-character)

Comment: [UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3942888/995714)

Comment: @phuclv so I fixed this specific error; but how can I globally handle these issues?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A workaround is to convert all text to latin-1 encoding before passing it on to the library. You can do that with the following command:

```
text2 = text.encode('latin-1', 'replace').decode('latin-1')
```

`text2` will be free of any non-latin-1 characters. However, some chars may be replaced with `?`

Comment: does this work in Python 3...I'm hving issues gettiing thiss to work. I can converrt it to a string wtih ? however the fpdf still rejects it...

Comment: Yes, I ran this with Python 3 too

Comment: My ' are all coming out at ?....have you used the font subsitution method where you define a UTF8 font?

Comment: This is the solution. To add in this answer you can ignore it as well using: 
text.encode('latin-1', 'ignore').decode('latin-1')

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this error is that you are trying to render a character in your PDF that is outside the code range of `latin-1` encoding. FPDF uses `latin-1` as default encoding for all its build-in fonts.

So as a workaround you can just remove all characters from your text that do not fit into `latin-1` encoding. (see my other answer for this workaround).

To fix this error and be able to render those characters in your PDF you need to use fonts that support a wider range of characters. To address this the FPDF library supports Unicode font.

For example you could get the free [Google Noto fonts](https://www.google.com/get/noto/), which support a wide range of Unicode endpoints. For most western languages I would recommend the NotoSans font set. But you can also get fonts for many other languages and scripts including Chinese, Hebrew or Arabic.

Here is how to enable the Unicode fonts in your code for FPDF:

First you need to tell FPDF library where it can find the font files. In this example I am setting it to the sub-folder `fonts` of the current folder.

```
import fpdf
fpdf.set_global("SYSTEM_TTFONTS", os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'fonts'))
```

Then you need to add the fonts to your PDF document. In this example I am adding the NotoSans fonts for the styles normal, bold, italic and bold-italic:

```
pdf = fpdf.FPDF()
pdf.add_font("NotoSans", style="", fname="NotoSans-Regular.ttf", uni=True)
pdf.add_font("NotoSans", style="B", fname="NotoSans-Bold.ttf", uni=True)
pdf.add_font("NotoSans", style="I", fname="NotoSans-Italic.ttf", uni=True)
pdf.add_font("NotoSans", style="BI", fname="NotoSans-BoldItalic.ttf", uni=True)
```

Now you can use the new fonts normally in your PDF document with `set_font()`. Here is an example for normal text:

```
pdf.set_font("NotoSans", size=12)
```

Comment: I tried this solution and got this error  ```AttributeError: module 'fpdf' has no attribute 'set_global'``` any specific version of fpdf recommended. It gives the error at ```fpdf.set_global...```. I skipped the set_global and gave relative path in ```pdf.add_font(..``` and it works  ```pdf.add_font("NotoKufiArabic", style="", fname="./fonts/NotoKufiArabic-Regular.ttf", uni=True)```

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the encoding through the `.set_doc_option()` method (documentation [here](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/set_doc_option/index.html#core_fonts_encoding)). I tried Erik's method, which worked for me, but then after adding some more complexities (such as a second PDF and using the write_html() method which required creating a new class), I went back to having the same error. Changing the encoding for the whole document should solve the overall problem as you said.

The readthedocs page says you can only use latin-1 or windows-1252, but `pdf.set_doc_option('core_fonts_encoding', 'utf-8')` worked for me according to the debugger. Just be aware that some characters will need fixing, like the apostrophe (') showing as Ã¢Â€ÂTM in the PDF.

Hope this is the global fix for this issue you were looking for, even if several months late!

Comment: not working, 'FPDF' object has no attribute 'set_doc_option'

Answer (score 0):

I was trying Erik's solution with some changes, works great with a mix of English and Arabic text. Sample code posted below to generate PDF using pyFPDF.

```
from datetime import datetime
def getFileName():
    now=datetime.now()
    time = now.strftime('%d_%H_%M_%S')
    filename = "Test_"+time + ".pdf"
    return filename


from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF()

#Download NotoSansArabic-Regular.ttf from Google noto fonts
pdf.add_font("NotoSansArabic", style="", fname="./fonts/NotoSansArabic-Regular.ttf", uni=True)


pdf.add_page()

pdf.set_font('Arial', '', 12)
pdf.write(8, 'Hello World')
pdf.ln(8)

# مرحبا Marhaba in arabic 
pdf.set_font('NotoSansArabic', '', 12)
text = 'مرحبا'
pdf.write(8, text)
pdf.ln(8)

pdf.output(getFileName(), 'F')
```