# FPDF Cyrillic letters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a PDF file from python with Cyrillic letters.

My code here doesn't work:

```
from fpdf import FPDF
pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font('arial')
text = 'а'
pdf.cell(10,10,text,0,1)
pdf.output('out.pdf', 'F')
```

When doing this, I got this error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u0430' in
> position 50: ordinal not in range(256)

How can I create a PDF file from python with Cyrillic letters?

Comment: this question has been asked here [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56761449/unicodeencodeerror-latin-1-codec-cant-encode-character-u2013-writing-to)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the _complete_ error traceback.