# UnicodeEncodeError while sending REST request using HTTP requests: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2013'

Tags: python-3.x, http, python-requests

While this problem is discussed in other questions, my case is happening with the HTTP client's requests library. I tried some of the suggested solutions (e.g. utf-8 encoding of request payload - payload=payload.encode("UTF-8"), str(payload), etc. mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56761449/unicodeencodeerror-latin-1-codec-cant-encode-character-u2013-writing-to)), but it did not my case. Looking for some clues. Will upgrading Python version in the virtual env help?

Code snippet #1.

```
def test_get_server_status_lhs(url, token):
    url = url + 'platform/v2/server/query'

    headers = {
        'Authorization': token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache'
    }
    payload = "{}"
    rest_api = RestApi()
    response = rest_api.post(url=url, payload=payload.encode("UTF-8"), headers=headers, verify=False)
    return response
```

Code snippet #2.

```
import ast
import base64
import json
import requests
import logging


log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class RestApi:
    def __init__(self):
        self.headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}

    def get(self, url, params=None, headers=None, verify=False):
        resp = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers, verify=verify)
        return resp

    def put(self, url, payload, headers=None, verify=False):
        resp = requests.put(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers, verify=verify)
        return resp

    def post(self, url, payload=None, headers=None, verify=False):
        if payload:
            resp = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, verify=verify)
        else:
            resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, verify=verify)
        return resp

    def delete(self, url, headers=None, verify=False):
        resp = requests.delete(url, headers=headers, verify=verify)
        return resp
```

Exception/error log.

```
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR: Caught an exception while executing section test_get_server_status_lhs:
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR:   File "/Users/test/workspace/test_server_settings.py", line 105, in test_get_server_status_lhs
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR:     token=lhs_http_token)
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR:   File "/Users/test/workspace/utils/rest/server_rest_apis.py", line 85, in rest_get_server_status
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR:     response = rest_api.post(url=url, payload=payload.encode("UTF-8"), headers=headers, verify=False)
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR:   File "/Users/test/workspace/utils/rest/base_rest_api.py", line 33, in post
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR:     resp = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, verify=verify)
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR:   File "/Users/test/pyvenv/pyvenv_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 119, in post
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR:     return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR:   File "/Users/test/pyvenv/pyvenv_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR:     return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR:   File "/Users/test/pyvenv/pyvenv_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR:     resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR:   File "/Users/test/pyvenv/pyvenv_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR:     r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR:   File "/Users/test/pyvenv/pyvenv_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR:     timeout=timeout
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR:   File "/Users/test/pyvenv/pyvenv_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 706, in urlopen
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR:     chunked=chunked,
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR:   File "/Users/test/pyvenv/pyvenv_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 394, in _make_request
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR:     conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR:   File "/Users/test/pyvenv/pyvenv_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 234, in request
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR:     super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR:   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1277, in request
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR:     self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR:   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1318, in _send_request
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR:     self.putheader(hdr, value)
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR:   File "/Users/test/pyvenv/pyvenv_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 219, in putheader
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR:     _HTTPConnection.putheader(self, header, *values)
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR:   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1250, in putheader
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR:     values[i] = one_value.encode('latin-1')
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-ERROR: UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 60: ordinal not in range(256)
2023-12-13T10:06:38: %AETEST-INFO: The result of section test_get_server_status_lhs is => ERRORED
```