# TFPDF Lithuanian letters

Tags: php, character-encoding, fpdf

I have a problem with lithuanian letters like `ąčęėįšųūž`. For that reason I use `tfpdf` and font `DejaVu`. When I get content from `txt` file, everything is fine but I give content just simply, then I get "????". Header charset is set `utf-8`.

```
ob_start();
require('../fpd/tfpdf.php');

$pdf = new tFPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

// Add a Unicode font (uses UTF-8)
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf',true);
$pdf->SetFont('DejaVu','',10);

// Load a UTF-8 string from a file and print it
$txt = file_get_contents('../fpd/HelloWorld.txt');
$pdf->Write(8,$txt);
$pdf->Ln(10);
$txt1 = "ąčęėįšųž";
$pdf->Write(8,$txt1);

$pdf->Output('filename1.pdf', 'I');

ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: I also tried utf8_decode() but there's no difference

Comment: did you try Arial font ?

Comment: Where do you have the problem? How do you use? Any code ? Example ?

Comment: also check this answer to know what you should do about the encoding stuff http://stackoverflow.com/a/9058876/3615630

Comment: Yes, I tried Arial but it was rubbish. I added my code in post.

Comment: Mohammad I already checked it, but i didn't find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to set the header to UTF-8 but your editor have to be configured to use UTF-8. To verify that this is the issue, open the PHP file in e.g. Notepad++, click on "Encoding" and check the current encoding. You may convert it to UTF-8 (without BOM!!) in the same step and try again.