# Echo special characters from mysql string not working

Tags: mysql, string, echo, special-characters, php-7

I had a working code and moved it to a new server, from php5 to php7.
Googling for a week did not help me, so i'm asking you guys.

I have some info with a euro-sign in a sql database: â‚¬99.00
The info is stored as utf16-general-ci.

If the info is selected and put in a string, i echo it with:
echo `$row["Total"]`;

On the old server it showed: `€99.00`
On the new server it shows: `â‚¬99.00`

I want to show the euro-sign instead of the character code.

I tried changing to utf-8, but this does nothing. Also `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()` does not do anything.

Comment: And when you don't expect, you find the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35234129/how-to-convert-windows-1252-characters-to-values-in-php

Comment: That's great that you found the answer to your formatting answer, but can I ask why you are storing a total as a string instead of a numeric format like a FLOAT or DECIMAL? This format would problematic if you ever wanted to run a query that treats the column like a number.

Answer (score 0):

As found in the link [How to convert Windows-1252 characters to values in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35234129/how-to-convert-windows-1252-characters-to-values-in-php)

The problem is the *Windows-1252* vs *ISO-8859-1*.

To fix the problem, i used:

`mb_convert_encoding($row["Total"], "Windows-1252", "UTF-8")`

More info can be found here: https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/bug-iso8859-1-vs-windows-1252.html