# How to set charset UTF-8 in PHP Invoicr script

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm using https://github.com/farjadtahir/pdf-invoicr.

Problem is when I add diacritics to `$invoice->setFrom()` (or anywhere else) diacritics not showing up.

I tried `$invoice->setFrom(array(iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1","ÆØÅ")`from [this comments](https://codecanyon.net/item/invoicr-php-class-for-beautiful-invoices/8829220/comments)
but still diacritics not working.

Next I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/21555497/2893691 again not working.

So, how to finally convert `ľščťžýáíé` to UTF-8 in invoicr?

**EDIT - NEW INFO**

I'm used `mb_detect_encoding()` and return is `UTF-8` already. But when I try show for example string `ičo123` the result is empty. Not showing.

I tried add `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` and still diacritics not working.

**EDIT 2 - NEW INFO**

I tried this script http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php and still not working. Here is screenshot of downloaded example from link above:

[image]

Comment: Convert it into HTML Entities and do it. That's the best I can think of.

Comment: FPDF not allow HTML Entities. `Č` is in PDF file `&CCARON;`

Comment: Problem solved - Used script from **EDIT 2**, removed all `iconv()` functions from `phpinvoice.php` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved - Used script from **EDIT 2** and removed all `iconv()` functions from `phpinvoice.php` file.