# FPDF Output file name encoding

Tags: php, utf-8, encode, fpdf

Im using FPDF to create some pdf documents, filename is taken from a field $fullname.
In document everything works fine , i get all the letter which i need with tFPDF.
Letters: **Š Đ Č Ć Ž**

But the problem is when the file is saved. Like i said the file name takes the $fullname, if i type inside a field my name " **Elvedin Salkanović** " i get the same in document, but name of the file on my localhost is " **Elvedin SalkanoviÄ‡.pdf** " So instead of **ć** i got **Ä‡**. And i reallz cant find the answer how to fix it.
I need utf-8 to be used for filename.
Btw I`m not an expert in php, so it would be nice if someone explain me deatailed.

Comment: Is it for windows or linux?

Comment: It is for windows

Comment: take a look on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334134/fpdf-utf-8-encoding-how-to

Comment: This is about text inside document encode, and i need the output file to be encoded.

Answer (score 0):

$filename=iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-9//TRANSLIT",$filename);

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$outputname = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $fullname);
```

[Source](https://isabelcastillo.com/international-characters-encoding-fpdf)

Comment: could you please a litttle bit more