# Support for unicode characters in FPDF library

Tags: php, fpdf

I am using the FPDF library to generate a pdf, I want to write Hindi and Marathi text in that but it display's only English text. I tried adding 'Devnagari' fonts using makeFont.php but still it doesn't work.Below is my code that adds text to a pdf

```
     $pdf->SetXY(0,210);
     $pdf->SetLeftMargin(28);
     $pdf->SetRightMargin(28);
     $pdf->AddFont('mangal','','mangal.php');
     $pdf->SetFont('mangal','',11);
     $pdf->Write(2,'खालील आपली भाषा');
```

[image: This is what I am getting in PDF]

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/a/21530540/1023432

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FPDF utf-8 encoding (HOW-TO)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334134/fpdf-utf-8-encoding-how-to)

Comment: I already have a pdf file and I want to use it as a source file in iFPDF library. I tried accessing it like this $pdf->setSourceFile('Section-478(1)30.pdf'); but its not working.Is there any way to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hade the same problem some years ago. I used then [tFPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php) and it solved the issue.

You may want to try it? The tFPDF class-file and an example are provided there: http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php

Have a nice day

Comment: I already have a pdf file and I want to use it as a source file in iFPDF library. I tried accessing it like this $pdf->setSourceFile('Section-478(1)30.pdf'); but its not working.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with iFPDF. Is that somethink with php? Do you have a weblink where I can download it so see what you mean?

Comment: sorry I mean tFPDF library that was typo

Comment: Sorry, I did not do that before, so I suggest that you somehow write a new question with that topic because it is a kind of new question