# How can we show emoji in pdf using fpdf library

Tags: php, emoji, fpdf

I’m utilizing the FPDF library to create a PDF file generated from individuals’s submitted messages and pictures on a zend web application.

If somebody tries to incorporate emojis of their messages, they show unusually within the ultimate PDF file.

For instance, if somebody submits the next string:

Simply testing emojis work  ❤️

The ultimate end result within the PDF file seems like this:

Simply testing emojis work ðŸ’ƒðŸ•» â•¤ï¸•Â ðŸ¥³

I need a help to show emoji in PDF using FPDF. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Emoji are not supported.

Comment: Try this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/9058876/13353861](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9058876/13353861)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FPDF utf-8 encoding (HOW-TO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334134/fpdf-utf-8-encoding-how-to)

Comment: Ever find a solution to this?